# How to make a specific peace of code visible when there is a match on a Route? react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im trying to display a dropdown that is inside my header, but the dropdown only has to be visible when there is match on a specific Route. Meanwhile the rest of the header should still be visible no matter what route.

```
const MatchedRoute = whatEverTheLogicToAssignTheRoute=="/thisRoute"
if (MatchedRoute) {
  return(
   <Dropdown />
   ...
  )
}
```

Btw I'm using react-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get which route you are on with

```
this.props.location.pathname
```

Logic:

```
const MatchedRoute = this.props.location.pathname === "/thisRoute"
if (MatchedRoute) {
  return(
   <Dropdown />
   ...
  )
}
```

Also you did not bind your `renderUserDropdown` function. Make use of arrow functions or do it in contructor

```
renderUserDropdown = () => {
  //content here

}
```

or

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.renderUserDropdown = this.renderUserDropdown.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: it throws me the following error:
Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Comment: can you show more of your code, also can you console.log(this.props) and see what you get

Comment: This is the code for the header component https://ibb.co/eA1fLk and this is the console log result : https://ibb.co/duiufk

Comment: Thanks for the help!, I guess the constructor did the work.